# Prove that for every prime number $|\{1\leq x \leq p^2 : p^2 | (x^{p-1}-1) \}|=p-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Show that for every prime number $p$:

$$|\{1\leq x \leq p^2 : p^2 | (x^{p-1}-1) \}|=p-1$$

I'm not really sure how to approach this, any ideas?

Comment: Also here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766523/1%E2%89%A4x%E2%89%A4p2p2xp-1-1-p-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be a generator of the [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_odd_primes) group $(\mathbb Z/ p^2\mathbb Z)^\times$, whose order is $\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)$,  and define $\xi=g^{p-1}$. Then any invertible $1\leq x\leq p^2-1$ can be put in the form $x\equiv g^k\pmod{p^2}$ for some $1\leq k\leq p(p-1)$.

Now, if $x$ is such that $x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$, then $x$ is invertible so $x\equiv g^k\pmod{p^2}$ and $\xi^{k}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$, and since the order of $\xi$ is $p$, it follows that $k$ is multiple of $p$. There are exactly $p-1$ multiples of $p$ between $1$ and $p(p-1)$, hence the result.

Comment: What about $x$ that is not invertible?

Comment: $x$ must be invertible because $x^{p-1}=1$ implies that $x^{p-2}$ is the inverse of $x$.

Comment: Very nice proof. I'm still a little confused, how can you be sure there aren't any more conditions on $k$ ? it seems the number is $\leq p-1$

Comment: Just take any $k$ multiple of $p$. Then $k(p-1)$ is multiple of $p(p-1)$, and so $x^{p-1}=g^{k(p-1)}=1$ since the order of $g$ is $p(p-1)$. This proves that $k$ satisfies the desired condition.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!